# How to store socket on localStorage/use socket on different components on vanilla ReactJS for use in different components socket.io?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, mern

I want to store the socket so I can use it in different components.
When I first set the socket on socket.io after login, I set the socket as a state under "socket" state and then store it on localStorage.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(!socket) {
            setSocket(io(backendLink));
        };
    }, []) 

useEffect(() => {
        socket?.emit("newUser", localStorage.getItem('authToken'));
        localStorage.setItem('socket', JSON.stringify(socket));
    }, [socket])
```

Then in different components, where I did not initially set the socket. I use logic like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(!socket) socket = localStorage.getItem('socket');
        socket.emit(...)
}, [userID])
```

Above, if the socket passed as props that was stored in state is null, i restore the socket from localStorage and use it to emit. However, I get Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON.

From what I understood, this is because I used JSON.stringify on something that cannot be converted and stored on localStorage this way i.e socket. I want to use vanilla reactjs to use the socket across as different files from the file i used setSocket(io(backendLink)). How to use socket.io across different components with vanilla reactJS(no context, completely vanilla)?

Comment: It's not a good idea to store the connection object as a string in the localStorage

Comment: How should I use the socket across different files then from where I initially set the socket with vanilla reactjs?

Comment: You can connect it to the top component and then share it using context.

Comment: You can use context or redux.

Comment: Like if i store as state and pass as props for the socket, I get null on the state after page refresh. It only works the first time, so I had to use localStorage, where I verify if the socket is null, restore from localStorage, but it's not working.

Comment: Okay. Thank you the quick response. I did not want to use either context or redux since I am a beginner. But it seems like I don't  have much of an option. Thanks. I'll see if I can use context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not stringify such objects, if you want to reference it across your application, you need to just to place it inside a React context after you saved it in the state. That way you can access it wherever you want across your application. There are other options too, but that's the safer one.

Comment: Is there no way to do it with reactjs without context?

Comment: Yes you can store the socket in a POJO, and retrieve it in every component that you need, but that solution needs you to know what you are doing, since you need to make sure on first mount of main parent, the socket is created and stored correctly.

Using React state and context is the safest way if you are not very experienced

Comment: When I refresh the page, I lose state. Is context going to solve this as well? Seems like all the other stackoverflow posts recommended localStorage for it. But does context also solve this issue?

Comment: When you refresh the page, you should create a new socket instance and reconnect it, what is the problem ? The socket instance doesn't keep an internal state, so what are you tryin to persist ?

Comment: Like after refresh, if the socket is null, then I execute this: if(!socket){setSocket(io(backendLink));};? If I do this, won't it be repetitive? I was trying to know how I understand how to use the socket I created on one file, and use it on other components.

Comment: You just have to create a socket instance inside a useEffect with [] dep on the App component which should be the highest component in your Components Tree. Then save it in a React State. You can then inject it down through props, or better using a React Context. You don't need to check if `socket` already exists when you first instantiate it, since it doesn't exist  on the first App mount (aka refresh or first open). You just have to be careful to add socket.on() listeners in other components, inside a useEffect with [socket] deps, and check `if (socket)` before attaching them.

Comment: This answered it. Thank you so much for your time. Much love